# How to change width of TAB character in a Flex TextArea?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, text, textarea

Is it possible to change the width of an insert TAB character in a Flex TextArea?

I'm capturing `FocusEvent.KEY_FOCUS_CHANGE` events and manually inserting a `"\t"` into a text area styled with an embedded monospace font. By default, the TABs are being displayed two and a half monospace characters wide... I need them to display five monospace characters wide.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Is using a Flex4 RichEditableText an option?

Comment: Wouldn't this be an operating system specific thing? Or possibly font related.  I wouldn't expect any Flash APIs allow you to change this.

Comment: @Marty - Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately I'm on a tight schedule and thus tied to Flex 3.
@www.Flextras.com - I tried creating a custom font glyph that was 5 characters wide, but the text area didn't seem to like that. I'm hoping to achieve a work around in AS.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
<mx:Canvas>
    <mx:Script>
        [Bindable]
        public var myText:String;
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:TextArea id="textArea" text="{TabUtil.expand(myText)}" valueCommit="myText = TabUtil.contract(myText))" />
 </mx:Canvas>



  public class TabUtil
  {
       public static const SPACE:String = "     "; // Five spaces;
       public static function expand(text:String):String
       {
            return text.replace("\t",SPACE);
       }
       public static function contract(text:String):String
       {
            return text.replace(SPACE,"\t");
        }
   }
```

I forget the params of replace, but I think it may take a RegEx, in which case you'd need to tweak the above.  But it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The tabStops property of textFormat is what you are looking for. You can set the pixel values of where you want each tab to be placed.

`var tf:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
tf.tabStops = [100, 200, 300, 400];
myTextArea.mx_internal::getTextField().defaultTextFormat = tf;`